# Multiple R plots with tooltips in one figure?

Tags: r, tooltip, shiny, interactive, ggvis

I want to create a new figure with interactive `R-plots` (with tooltips). 
To show how I wish to have my plots I give an example using the `mtcars` data. I am using the package `scatterD3` to get tooltips:

```
library(scatterD3)
data(mtcars)
tooltips <- paste('This is an incredible <strong>',rownames(mtcars),'</strong><br />with',mtcars$cyl,'cylinders !')
scatterD3(x=mtcars$wt,y=mtcars$mpg,tooltip_text=tooltips)
```

Now I don't want only one plot of this type in one figure. Usually it is possible to use `par(mfrow=(i,j))` to create a figure with more than one plot. But it seems not to work for my interactive plots. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you given a look to the [plotly R package](https://plot.ly/r/)?

It has also a function to render the ggplots in [ggplotly](https://plot.ly/ggplot2/)

An idea could be to create a multiplot with ggplot2 and than render it with ggplotly.

I've not yet tried it, so I don't know if it's really possible.